# How to export a modified model(used for transfer learning, in .ckpt format) built on tensorflow to a frozen graph(.pb file)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, resnet

I'm trying to export a export this particular model from [argman/EAST](https://github.com/argman/EAST). The model is built separately and weights are loaded in the session when required. Is there a way where I can export the model to a frozen graph (.pb) file, from the session. Or is there any other way to do that? Model is built in [model.py file(line 33)](https://github.com/argman/EAST/blob/master/model.py) and weights are loaded to the model in [run_demo_server.py (line 54-57)](https://github.com/argman/EAST/blob/master/run_demo_server.py)

I've seen a bunch of scripts to convert ".ckpt" files to ".pb" but, all those scripts are asking for output node names, I'm not able to locate the output layer names. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this in google colab

```
!python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-xxxx --output_directory inference_graph
```

or this in cmd

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-XXXX --output_directory inference_graph
```